# asp.net(vb) read element values in xml

Tags: asp.net, xml, xml-parsing

If I have some xml in a string how can I read through and pick out the values of each element? What;s the quickest and easiest way?

```
    Dim strXml As String = "<subscription>"
    strXml = strXml & "<reference>abc123</reference>"
    strXml = strXml & "<status>active</status>"
    strXml = strXml & "<customer>"
    strXml = strXml & "<fname>Joe</fname>"
    strXml = strXml & "<lname>bloggs</lname>"
    strXml = strXml & "<company>Bloggs inc</company>"
    strXml = strXml & "<phone>1234567890</phone>"
    strXml = strXml & "<email>joebloggs@hotmail.com</email>"
    strXml = strXml & "</customer>"
    strXml = strXml & "</subscription>"
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Linq to xml like the following code:

```
    Dim xmlE As XElement = XElement.Parse(strXml)

    Dim str As String = (From el In xmlE.Elements("customer").Elements("fname")
                        Select el.Value).Single()
```